# how to copy and paste in powershell without losing formatting

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

While copying my.ps1 file from my local to remote system, it is loosing it's formatting.

in my local(part of that script):

> {..some code here..([scriptblock]::Create(”. {$script} $(&{$args}
> @params)”))}

after copying to my remote, it becomes:

> {..some code here..([scriptblock]::Create(â€. {$script} $(&{$args} @params)â€))}

What should I need to do for my.ps1 script while copying ?

Comment: Those aren't *normal* quotes.

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue.  How are you copying the file?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Ah, "smart" quotes strike again! They are definitely not normal quotes. Money: Delete the quotes in your original script and put in the proper characters. This is most often seen when copying scripts out of Microsoft Word or other document/website formats.

Answer (score 0):

Always save your code as `UTF-8 with BOM` to preserve your characters as is.

When setting up VS Code (if that is the editor you are using), that is one of the first things I always do.

File - Preferences - Settings
Files: Encoding